# Java Packages - refer to a class from a different package

Tags: java, package

In the (default package) I have a class called "Bird" that has a method called "dialog".

I can create a class called Class1 within the same package, like this:

```
public class Class1
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Bird b = new Bird("Alexander",true,5);
        b.dialog("tweet!");
    }
}
```

This actually works and I actually get to see `tweet!` in the console.

My question is: what do I need to add in the code if `Class1` is located in the package `Fundamental`  (whereas the class `Bird` is located in the "default package")?
I get an error: "Bird type not recognised" in this case. I should probably indicate the package somehow.

Side questions: 1. What is a classpath and how do you change it? I have seen this term vaguely used in the context of several package-related discussions, but none with clear examples as I just gave. 
2. I have seen many times packages called xxx.bla.zzz - is this a standard? I only usually use a common name (not three separated by .)
I understand a package is Java's replacement for namespaces in other languages. If there are several solutions solutions worth mentioning, I'd appreciate. Thank you!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java), http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Comment: stop using the default package.  You must either import the class or use the full package name of the class.  Move the Bird class to the `com.blammy` package and either add "import com.blammy.Bird" in Class1 or reference it as `com.blammy.Bird` in Class1

Comment: Thank you Dave, I checked your first link and it resembles other discussions that I found that are unclear. It looks very formal and excessively theorical to me. Why would I need a command line like this: java -classpath D:\myprogram;D:\myprogram\lib\supportLib.jar org.mypackage.HelloWorld ? Why not just indicate inside Class1 that I call class Bird from package x. If inside a project I have many such occurrences, do I put the project on hold and run it by pieces and stop to insert a command line, then resume the rest of the classes, etc?

Comment: I might have 20 different packages in a complex project. I realise just now I haven't tested what happens if Class1 is located in a package inside the main package, if there is even the concept of nested packages.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should never use the default package, it is not a good practice and you can't import classes from the default package. Always declare your package structure.

In the class `Bird` in the first line add:

```
package animals;
```

In the first line of your Class1.java write your package name

```
package foo;

import animals.Bird;
```

Note that for this to work the class `Bird` and the class `Class1` should be respectively in the folder "animals" and the folder "foo"

Comment: Thank you so much fmsf and Peter! This is what I was looking for. I didn't know that Peter, I was actually hoping someone would touch that case of default versus generated packages, since I was curious how to refer a package with apparently no name (the default one). Great tips, and simple as I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

According to JLS (Chapter 7.5. Import Declarations http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5) it is impossible to import from default (unnamed) package

*A type in an unnamed package (§7.4.2) has no canonical name, so the requirement for a canonical name in every kind of import declaration implies that (a) types in an unnamed package cannot be imported, and (b) static members of types in an unnamed package cannot be imported. As such, §7.5.1, §7.5.2, §7.5.3, and §7.5.4 all require a compile-time error on any attempt to import a type (or static member thereof) in an unnamed package.*

Answer (score 2):

The solutions offerd so far are helpfull but if you are using NetBeans it is quite simpler to solve the problem. Go to the project right click and select open new package. NetBeans provides you a Dialog for creating the new package. This is where the trick is, NOTE: ensure your new project name does not begin with the same name as the other packages so that the new package will be uniquely identified.Give the new package a different name for example

```
newPackage;
```

You can then use the import statement  on the class  file you expect to use the package in:

```
import newPackage.SecondClass;
```

You can actualy use the code completion ctr + spaceBar to ensure the package is well visible.

I expect this is simple enough.
[check out this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGhgv.png)