# Public class inside package can't see public interface?

Tags: java

I have a class:

```
package Member;
public class Player implements Character{
...
}
```

and I have interface that is not inside the package:

```
public interface Character{
...
}
```

I think that public intefaces and classes are visible to each other no matter if they are in the same package, so why I can't implement Character in the Player class? I have error: Cannot resolve symbol 'Character'

Comment: Did you import the interface? Or is the interface in the unnamed package?

Comment: You can't access types in the [unnamed package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.4.2) from any other package. Put them into a named package instead (i.e. have *some* `package`  statement in the secon file).

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate: [Import package with no name Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33645950/import-package-with-no-name-java), [How to access a class whose .java file has no package statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23494084/how-to-access-a-class-whose-java-file-has-no-package-statement), [Java Packages - refer to a class from a different package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592738/java-packages-refer-to-a-class-from-a-different-package)

Comment: @JoachimSauer The only solution is to put interface inside a named package?

Comment: @Pawlinho: yes, the unnamed package shouldn't be used for anything but the simplest test programs (as described in the link I gave above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the interface (or any other class/enum you use) are in a different package, you need to either fully qualify it:

```
public class Player implements org.somepackage.Character {
```

or import it:

```
import org.somepackage.Character;
public class Player implements Character {
```

Comment: This is not incorrect, but I think OPs problem is that `Character` is in the unnamed package. He won't be able to import that.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I think OP's confusion is that they thought "visible to other packages" meant "not even imports are needed".